# How do I pass parameters from Child to Parent in Azure RunBooks

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-automation, runbook

So, one would think this would be pretty simple, but I've been dealing with this for a few days now.

Basically it's like this:

Parent.ps1

```
  #calling the childrunbook
./childrunbook.ps1 -FirstName 'John'-LastName 'Snow'
 $newGreeting = $greeting + 'John Snow'
 Write-Output $newGreeting
```

Child.ps1

```
param(
   [string]$Firstname, 
   [string]$Lastname
)

$greeting = 'Hello from the Child Runbook'
Write-Output $greeting
```

Result

```
#I was hoping to get 
"Hello from the Child Runbook John Snow"
#But all I'm getting is:
"John Snow"  :-(
```

I can do this easily in Powershell, but once I put this same code in Powershell Runbooks on Azure, it's a no go. I thought it might have been a single quote/double quote issue but that hasn't led to any progress. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you just run a script like this:

```
./childrunbook.ps1 -FirstName 'John'-LastName 'Snow'
```

it executes in it's own *scope* - meaning that anything written to variables inside the script will only modify a *local copy* of that variable, and the changes won't touch anything in the parent scope.

In order to execute the script in the *calling scope*, use the dot source operator `.`:

```
. ./childrunbook.ps1 -FirstName 'John'-LastName 'Snow'
```

---

Alternatively you'd just assign the output from the child script to a variable in the calling scope:

```
$greeting = ./childrunbook.ps1 -FirstName 'John'-LastName 'Snow'
$newGreeting = $greeting + 'John Snow'
Write-Output $newGreeting
```

Comment: Thank you @Mathias R. Jessen I owe you a beer!